# SQLCMD run a query file

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I need to run SQL query on a SQL Server database from command line, the following query run on SSMS without any issue. first I created a file (MyScript.sql):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_tokenize(@input VARCHAR(MAX))
   RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
   RETURN (SELECT CAST('<r><![CDATA[' + @input + ' ' + ']]></r>' AS XML).value('(/r/text())[1] cast as xs:token?','VARCHAR(MAX)'));
END
GO

UPDATE dbo.PMDOCS
SET SDESC = dbo.udf_tokenize(SDESC);
```

Then I run a sqlcmd on the command line:

```
sqlcmd -S EC2AMAZ-5UNBD90 -d   miadmfggp_live -i "C:\MyScript.sql"
```

I got the following error:

```
SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.
```

Please advise how to fix it. Thanks